# Encoding and Decoding png in base64

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, base64

I am trying to format an uploaded .png file in my angular front-end so that it can be stored in a database. I am having some issues which I have replicated in this single function. I am taking the `data` field passed into this function, which represents the png file and encoding it in base64. However, I can't tell if it is working. In this example, I encode the item and then instantly decode it, but the outputs don't equal each other?

```
  addImage(data: any): Observable<File> {
    console.log('original', data);
    const encodedImg: Image = new Image();
    encodedImg.img = {data: btoa(data), contentType: 'image/png'};
    console.log('encoded', encodedImg);
    console.log('final', atob(encodedImg.img.data), encodedImg.img.contentType);
    return this.http.post<File>('/api/image', encodedImg);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: the variable `data` is a File object, so basically meta-data about the file which you can see printed out in the first line. And btw., it's a jpg, not a png. The base64 that you create `W29iamVjdCBGaWxlXQ==` has the content: `[object File]`.

Comment: @jps Thanks for that - I think I am now getting some much better results. The file is being written to the db (I believe correctly). When inspecting the db, I am seeing new records being created, which look like they have a good structure. However, now when I GET the file, I am returned with some JSON e.g. (`{"img":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[87,50,57,105,97,109,86,106,100,67,66,71,98,51,74,116,82,71,70,48,89,86,48,61]},"contentType":"image/png"},"_id":"60eb1d3dd0b6fd065673357c","__v":0}`. Do I need to encode this, or am I still facing issues with the original file save?

Comment: The data part in  `[ ]`are decimal ASCII-Codes, 87->W, 50->2, 57->9 and so on. It's just the same base64 code as in your original question, so still not the image data but the string as mentioned in my other comment. You need to read the file instead of encoding the File object.